# Get System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MetaModel from any database

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, mapping, information-schema

I am developing an app that has to do some work with the `InformationSchema` of `SQL Server` databases. So far, I am able to retrieve that information by doing the following:

```
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES", conn);

            SqlDataReader dataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable.Load(dataReader);
```

This works as expected. But this way I have to be working with `DataTables` which is not too convenient to me.

So, after some research I found that by using `Linq to Sql` one can be able to obtain a **`System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MetaModel`** which basically contains all the info about tables and columns of the database:

```
        MyDatabaseDataContext context = new MyDatabaseDataContext (connection);

        var tables = context.Mapping.GetTables();

        // do some work
```

The problem for me is that apparently that info is only retrieved when the mappings are specified in the code:

```
    // these lines of code are generated by the sqlmetal.exe tool
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Id", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
    public int Id
    {
```

So, for that reason I cannot retrieve that by doing this:

```
        System.Data.Linq.DataContext context = new System.Data.Linq.DataContext(conn);

        var tables = context.Mapping.GetTables();
```

Beacuse it returns nothing, even when the database does have tables.

So, **Is there a way to retrieve a `System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MetaModel` for any database without generating its custom `DataContext`??**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The main things that get generated by SqlMetal are classes that are mapped to database tables. Without them a DataContext means nothing. It can't generate mappings all by itself.